# How to overwrite a new project to an already existing repository?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I've had to delete an existing Visual Studio project linked up to a repo on my GitHub, due to the project being corrupted.

So I've downloaded a zip of the project from GitHub before it got corrupted and deleted the existing project on my machine, in place of the downloaded error free version.

But when I tried to commit to GitHub with this new version, using the Team Foundation Server plugin in VS13, the Git repo URL is required.

My question, Is there a way I can push this new local copy of the project to the already existing repo on GitHub using TFS? Essentially make it the new master branch for that existing repository, due to the original local project being deleted as it was corrupted.

The screen displayed when I tried to commit the new changes to the new project copy:

[image: tfs]

Comment: Why not clone from github and revert to the non-corrupted state. After all, that's the very point of git. git does not loose your history!

Comment: Does cloning mean, cloning a copy from my online repo? If so will the repository connection still be present, ie, I'll still be able to commit to that repo as normal from the clone. Not quire sure how to do that either.

Comment: I do not know the Visual Studio interface. But in my opinion it should expose an option to clone the repository, and then this new clone should have a "repository connection" (called remote in git-speak) in place.

Comment: @SebastianRiese You can clone a Git repo in Visual Studio.

Comment: This walkthrough helped me to clone the project, which has solved the issue for me, http://www.malgreve.net/2014/06/17/cloning-getting-code-from-git-repository-to-visual-studio/   feel free to create an answer on this solution if needs be.

Comment: Oh, I wrote the answer just to find that it's solved already. :) Now that you've found a solution, could you please check and possibly edit my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What probably happened is that you deleted your .git directory together with your old project. Now there's no repository on your machine and TFS has no idea where to push.

I would recommend you to start over by cloning from your GitHub repo. That can be done in Visual Studio or in command line.

**Command-line way:**

Just for backing up, save your current project where it is.
In a new directory clone the current project from github:

```
git clone https://github.com/YourName/repo_name.git
```

By any means find a commit of a stable version. Save it's sha1.

Backup, reset, push to repo.

```
#that's our backup of master
git checkout master
git checkout -b backup
#can save it on the remote, but that's not necessary
git push -u origin

#return to a stable version on local
git checkout master
git reset --hard <sha1 of stable commit>

#and save changes on GitHub
git push --force origin/master
```

Now both GitHub and your local repo have stable versions. There's also a backup for times of nostalgy.